# Create many files via touch command

Tags: bash, files

I want to create files like `00001 00002 ... $i` **(i need these files to start with 0)** via touch command.
I tried lots  of things but it was unsuccessful.

**NOTE: I've an environmental variable like `` i=`ls -1 | wc -l` `` and i wanna use it in my case.**

I also tried these:

```
touch {01..$i}
touch {01..$(echo $i)}
touch {000001..00$i}
touch {000001..00$(($i))}
touch {000001..00$(($i+1-1))}
touch {000001..$(00$i)}
touch {000001..$((00$i))}
touch {000001..$(($i))}
touch {000001..$((00000+$i))}
touch {000001..$((00+$i))}
touch {000001..$((000+$i))}
touch {000001..$((0000+$i))}
touch {000001..$((echo 00$(($i)))}
touch {000001..$((echo "00$i"))}
touch {000001..$(($(echo "00$i")))}
touch {000001..$(echo -n "00$i")}
touch {000001..00echo -n $i}
touch {000001..00$((echo -n $i))}
touch {$i..000001}
touch {00$((i))..000001}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [seq](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/seq.1.html) to create the sequence of numbers and pipe its output into [xargs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xargs.1.html) to call `touch` for each number:

```
seq -w $i | xargs touch
```